# Google doesn't show a complete question title when it contains smart quotes

Tags: support, google

Google results linking to questions containing smart ("curly") quotes seem to only give part of the title.

e.g. the question [Converting ″Straight Quotes″ to “Curly Quotes”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202811/converting-straight-quotes-to-curly-quotes) (searchable through something like http://google.com/search?q=2202811+quotes) gives: 
`Converting ″Straight Quotes - Stack Overflow`.

Is this something Stack Overflow should try to work around, or is it Google's fault?  (Or both?)

Comment: I perform enough 'remove tag from title' edits that I will keep this in mind and remove them if I'm in an edit. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing smart about using those quotes -_-

Comment: @mwfearnley, Note that it's not just about straight quotes, I've seen this happening with many other unicode characters.

Comment: Presumably people are not going to be searching for `2202811 quotes` (particularly often). Do you have a (presumably) more common query which gives this result?

Comment: I've run into this with the Stack Exchange search and asked about it on Meta.SE.  That's  not quite the same as Google's search, of course, but special characters do seem to cause problems all around. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202610/225437, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202612/225437, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202417/225437.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the clue is here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en

> However, sometimes even pages with well-formulated, concise, descriptive titles will end up with different titles in our search results to better indicate their relevance to the query. There’s a simple reason for this: the title tag as specified by a webmaster is limited to being static, fixed regardless of the query. Once we know the user’s query, we can often find alternative text from a page that better explains why that result is relevant.

Searching for the text of the question 
[I have an application...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=I%20have%20an%20application%20which%20uses%20a%20Javascript-based%20rules%20engine.%20I%20need%20a%20way%20to%20convert%20regular%20straight%20quotes%20into%20curly%20(or%20smart)%20quotes.%20It%E2%80%99d%20be%20easy%20to%20just%20d&oq=I%20have%20an%20application%20which%20uses%20a%20Javascript-based%20rules%20engine.%20I%20need%20a%20way%20to%20convert%20regular%20straight%20quotes%20into%20curly%20(or%20smart)%20quotes.%20It%E2%80%99d%20be%20easy%20to%20just%20d&aqs=chrome..69i57.567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8&qscrl=1)
gives this result: 
[image: javascrit - converting straight quotes to curly quotes]

So it looks like it's used the query to modify the title of the page. As to why it does that, I'm not sure. It does look like Google's fault, and it's probably not worth trying to reverse engineer.